# Add Open OnClick event to script (React/JSX)

Tags: javascript, css, menu, reactjs

We have a menu built with JavaScript (React/JSX). Through styling, the manu item opens when hovered.

My questions:

1. Instead of using CSS to open the menu on hover, where in the code can I add an OnClick event so it opens the menu with JavaScript?
2. Is there a way to close the menu when an area outside of the menu is clicked? If so, where would the could reside and what would it be?

   var LanguageList = React.createClass({
       render: function() {
         return DOM.div({'id': 'language-menu', 'className': 'language-menu'},
                    DOM.a({'id':'language-selected',
            'className':'lm-arrow lang-item',
                   'href': 'http://google.com',
                   'title':'Google',
                    'dangerouslySetInnerHTML': {
                       '__html': 'Google'
                   }})
                   , DOM.ul({
           'id': 'language-list',
           'className': 'language-list'}
               , DOM.li({}, DOM.a({'className':'lang-item',
               'href': 'http://google.com/site1',
               'title':'Site1',
                'dangerouslySetInnerHTML': {
                   '__html': 'Site1'
               }}))

Comment: Just my advice. Make sure next time you format your question better. Most people here are busy people and they wont try to decode your question if you ask like this.
You should really thank "Davide Ungari" for answering it.

Answer (score 1):

Define an handler function before the *render* definition, then use this function as the value of the *onClick* attribute.

```
var LanguageList = React.createClass({
    handlerOnClick: function() { ... },
    render: function() {
        return DOM.div({
            'id': 'language-menu',
            'className': 'language-menu'},
            'onClick': this.handlerOnClick,
```

[This documentation should help you as well.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html)

Comment: Thank you ungarida. What would go here: { ... }?

Comment: It is the code you would like to trigger onClick event, it is the one you mentioned on part 1).